# Squirrell UpdateManager CheckForUpdate hangs - no logging

Tags: c#, squirrel.windows

The following line hangs forever.

```c#
  updateInfo = await mgr.CheckForUpdate();
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with acquiring a lock on a file? It's hard to diagnose without enabling logging. I was not able to enable logging per [these](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/using/debugging-updates.md) instructions. If I register a logger in my program as in either of the below lines of code, nothing is logged. I'm guessing because the context of the program is different from the context of the update.exe.

```c#
  Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => myLogger, typeof(Splat.ILogger));
  Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => myLogger2, typeof(Splat.IFullLogger));
```

Any help diagnosing the check-update or forcing the log would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's a know bug : [CheckForUpdate() doesn't return](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/1632)

It's the WebClient that deadlock when call from the main thread. The solution is to call Squirrel from a other thread, like :

```cs
static async Task CheckForUpdateSafe(this UpdateManager mgr)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await mgr.CheckForUpdate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found this today the hard way myself too after several days of debugging